# How do I make an arrow with curved edges

Tags: css

I used border-radius but it doesn't make all the edges round. I want to make a down angle arrow.

```css
.drop-arrow {
  border: solid #FFDD00;
  border-width: 0px 20px 20px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class='drop-arrow'></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on pseudo element to curve all the edges:

```css
.drop-arrow {
  --b:20px; /* border-width */

  border: solid #FFDD00;
  border-width: 0px var(--b) var(--b) 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius:var(--b);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin:30px;
  position:relative;
}
.drop-arrow::before,
.drop-arrow::after {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   width:var(--b);
   height:var(--b);
   background:#FFDD00;
   border-radius:50%;
}
.drop-arrow::before {
  top:calc(-1*var(--b)/2);
  right:0;
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
.drop-arrow::after {
  left:calc(-1*var(--b)/2);
  bottom:0;
  transform:translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<span class='drop-arrow'></span>

<span class='drop-arrow' style="--b:30px;"></span>
<span class='drop-arrow' style="--b:15px;"></span>
```

[image: CSS rounded arrow]

To add a rounded edge to the inside part, you can add a gradient coloration like below:

```css
.drop-arrow {
  --b:20px; /* border-width */

  border: solid #FFDD00;
  border-width: 0px var(--b) var(--b) 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius:var(--b);
  background:
   radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left,transparent 98%,#FFDD00 100%) 
    bottom -0.5px right -0.5px/var(--b) var(--b) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin:30px;
  position:relative;
}
.drop-arrow::before,
.drop-arrow::after {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   width:var(--b);
   height:var(--b);
   background:#FFDD00;
   border-radius:50%;
}
.drop-arrow::before {
  top:calc(-1*var(--b)/2);
  right:0;
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
.drop-arrow::after {
  left:calc(-1*var(--b)/2);
  bottom:0;
  transform:translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<span class='drop-arrow'></span>

<span class='drop-arrow' style="--b:30px;"></span>
<span class='drop-arrow' style="--b:15px;"></span>
```

[image: CSS curved arrow edge]

Answer (score -2):

Your code looks like you are using a font-framework with the arrow integretated - maybe something like https://fontawesome.com/.

There is no arrow in your css described. Have a look at the font you are using to find the symbol.
To get another arrow, either the font needs to support another arrow or you'll have to use another font/build your own font.